# Custom quantized ticks on axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a line-chart in d3js, which draws a graph of your performance over time. This means my data is a certain score at a certain point in time. Example:

```
2011-01-01: 75
2012-01-01: 83
2013-01-01: 50
```

Now I don't want to display the score as integer values on my Y-axis, but I'd like to map the integer values into useful words. Example:

```
a score between 50 and 70 means you've scored Excellent
a score between 25 and 50 means you've scored Very Good
etc.
```

**What's the best way for doing this?**

The implementation of my axis is as follows:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([settings.height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .ticks(5)
            .orient("left");

y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.score; }));

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("x", (settings.width - 10 ))
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text(settings.labels.y);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own `tickFormat`. For example:

```
function scoreFormat(d) {
    if (d <= 70 && d > 50) {
        return "Good";
    } else if (d <= 50 && d > 25) {
        return "Bad";
    }
    return "Ugly";
}

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return scoreFormat(d); });
```

Comment: you can just do `.tickFormat(scoreFormat)`

Answer (score 2):

Check out [d3.scale.quantize](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize-scales), which takes a domain similar to a linear scale but breaks it to discrete range values in even chunks.  If even sized chunks won't work for you, [d3.scale.threshold](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales) is a similar idea except you can define your own mapping between subsets of the domain and the discrete range values.